# Warning while setting "filter" css value in GWT UiBinder

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I have this following warning:

```
00:48:06.843 [WARN] [XXXX] Line 71 column 11: encountered ":". 
Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION>
```

In line `71` I have the following line

```
<ui:style>
...
    .menuPopup {
        position:absolute; 
        top: 5px; 
        right: -80px;
        width:100px; 
        background-color: #F2F2F2; 
        -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#888888',Direction=135, Strength=3);    
    }
</ui:style>
```

When i remove the `filter: progid:...` line it works fine.

Does GWT have a problem with the `filter` attribute?

Comment: The CSS parser must be complaining about the second colon. Should the entire filter value be in double quotes?

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy I tried this `filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#888888',Direction=135, Strength=3)";` but then IE doesn't recognize the style (shodow equivalent for `shadow`style)

Comment: Doing some microsoft specific thing that google wouldn't approve of, eh?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I have no choice you see, as usual, every browser has it's own google approved css shadow style except IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filter` does not follow the CSS grammar, so you have to use the [`literal()` function](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#Literal_function) of GWT's `CssResource`:

```
filter: literal("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#888888',Direction=135, Strength=3)");
```